# Data warehouse dimension design technique

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse

When implementing a development process to load data into a SCD2 dimension table, what is the most practical method of doing so for a scenario where there are multiple records in the staging table per BusinessKey in the Dimension table. 
The first issue in this scenario is that you have 2 or more records in your staging table that can update the IscurrentFlag, EffectiveToDate.

Is implementing a post process to recalculate IsCurrentRecord and EffectiveToDates after data is loaded the only solution?

**Scenario example:** 

The dimension table is populated from 1 source system. 
The source system table (Customer) from which the data is extracted contains history. Multiple updates can be done for the same customer in 1 day resulting in multiple records in the source system table

Dimension table :

[image: Example]

Staging Table :

[image: Example]

Comment: This is too abstract as stated. Sample data would help a lot.

Comment: Can you give us more details about your dimensions, facts, business logic ...?

Comment: How do you add tables to the question? I tried without any success

Comment: @EricBrandt- uploaded image example

Comment: For which attribute are you making SCD ?

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi- In this scenario, DateOfBirth column is SCD 2. Not a realistic example. I know

Comment: How can you present one certain value for a dimension as 'current', when different sources tell you different things about this value? The issue is not 'picking the right one', the question should be whether or not these values should be 'competing' for the same spot in your data model... If however they are describing the same thing, try to find out if one source is always considered as the lead system and load that one last.

Comment: @steenbergh The challenge is not in picking the right one as both staged records need to be loaded into the dimension table.